# How can I write a query to check if a collection is missing from the database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app in Flutter that uses Cloud Firestore to store user records. I also want to save the application settings to Cloud Firestore. For example, the application will use several design templates to choose from. Data about the current topic is written in the database.

The presented code works well with a collection that already exists in Cloud Firestore. When the application starts, the appropriate collection is checked and UserPreferencesManager() is called if data is available. But what to do when you first launch the application, when such a collection does not yet exist in the database? How do I go to PageForNewUser() where this collection will be created? The above code does not cope with this task.

How can I write a query to check if a collection is missing from the database? Or maybe there is a method to check if the logged-in user is a new user without any entries in the database.

Here is my code:

```
class CheckingUserStatus extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckingUserStatus({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckingUserStatus> createState() => _CheckingUserStatusState();
}

class _CheckingUserStatusState extends State<CheckingUserStatus> {

  final String? _email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email; //Получаем email текущего пользователя

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('$_email data').doc('data').collection('currentTemplate').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const UserPreferencesManager();
          }
          else { return const PageForNewUser();}

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Write An Function called `doesCollectionExist`

```
Future<bool> doesCollectionExist(String collectionName) async {
  // Reference to the Firestore database
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  // Query the specified collection
  QuerySnapshot collection = await firestoreInstance.collection(collectionName).get();

  // Check if the collection is empty
  return collection.docs.isNotEmpty;
}
```

And Call This

```
bool collectionExists = await doesCollectionExist('your_collection_name');

if (collectionExists) {
  print('The collection exists.');
} else {
  print('The collection does not exist.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write a query to check if a collection is missing from the database?

There is no query present that can help you check if a collection is missing. However, you can create a query that should return documents from the collection and add a `limit(1)` call. If you get a document, then the collection exists, otherwise it doesn't exist. Alternatively, you can [count](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) the documents.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.
I was able to solve my problem this way: I set the currentTemplate variable to 'notDefined'. Next, in initState I receive data from the database. If the collection exists, then the currentTemplate variable is assigned the value from the database. If the collection does not exist, then the value of the currentTemplate variable remains 'notDefined'. Next, in the build method, I call the classes I need in accordance with the value of the currentTemplate variable.
Now everything works, but a new problem has appeared. When the application starts, the screen corresponding to the notDefined value is briefly called up. And only then the screen corresponding to the value downloaded from the database is loaded. I think this is because it takes a while to get the data from the database.
How to avoid the wrong screen appearing when launching an application. I tried to solve this problem using asyns, await - it doesn’t work. Or I'm using them incorrectly.
Here is my code

```
class _CheckingUserStatusState extends State<CheckingUserStatus> {

  final String? _email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email; //Получаем email текущего пользователя
  String currentTemplate = 'notDefined';

  @override
  void initState() {

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('$_email data').doc('data').collection('currentTemplate').doc('currentTemplate').get()//Считываем число задач в группе
          .then(
            (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
          final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var entries = data.entries.toList(); //Переводим map в список
          String currentTemplateFromDB = entries.elementAt(0).value;// Из пары ключ-значение берем только значение и переводим строку в число

          setState(() {
            currentTemplate = currentTemplateFromDB;
          });
        },
      );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, //Эта строка кода разрешает экранной клавиатуре перекрывать виджеты
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {

          if (currentTemplate == 'default') {
            return const DefaultPage();
          }
          else if (currentTemplate == 'musicPlayer') {
            return const GroupsListPageMPT();
          }
          else if (currentTemplate == 'notDefined') {
            return const PageForNewUser();
          }
          else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post followup questions as an answer. An answer should be an answer and if there are additional questions, you should update the original question or post a separate question if it's a different issue.